# how to prevent client IP spoofing in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, security

I got an information security report after the Penetration Test or PEN test.

I am doing my project in .NET Core 3.1.

I am new to this type of issues.

Please give any code snippets that I can understand in C#. The issue is that the application is vulnerable to IP spoofing using x-forwarded-for http header.

Edit 1:
[image: This is normal request and response]

[image: This Request and Response from attacker as per Report]

Comment: 1) Ask the people that did the penetration test to elaborate on why it's a vulnerability. 2) Does your system use the IP address of the client for anything? If it doesn't, then do you care that people can spoof it?

Comment: It is only a informational and not low, medium or high risk threat, its time to how to prevent it while doing PEN test or their point of view. I am assigned this task I couldn't find any sufficient resources in developer view

Comment: You're trying to prevent something that isn't very clear. The pen testers probably made a request to your server with an x-forwarded-for header and saw something in the response that they didn't like. Find out what they saw and if it's a problem or not. When you know what the request and response was you'll also have a much better chance of getting help here.

Comment: @RaviHanok Good question. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ravi, based on your post, it seems like your app checks for the Request.UserHostAddress or Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") which is returning the client's IP and based on if the user is internal or external, you are returning different results.

If that is not the case, than this is a non-issue.
If that is the case, you need to ignore the X-FORWARDED-FOR header.

Search your code for X-FORWARDED-FOR and figure out what it does and how it is used for security checks.